# ffmpeg cut first and last second of every clip

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to make a batch operation for all files in a folder.
For every file I need to remove the first and last second of the clip, and save it to a destination folder.
This is the command I used:

```
for %f in (“*.*”) do c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%f" -ss 00:00:01.000 -sseof 00:00:01.000 -c:v copy -c:a copy “u:\footage\%f”
```

That command does not work. It cuts the first second but leave the rest of the file as is.
Maybe there is something I need to change in the syntax regarding `-sseof`.

Comment: “Smart quotes” are not usable in ffmpeg commands.

Answer (score 4):

`ss` and `sseof` both tell ffmpeg where to start from, so your command has two start times specified and no end time. Your command is preferring `ss` (possibly since it is closest to the input) and ignoring `sseof`, then working to the end of the file.

You can use `to` (which takes a position in the file) or `t` (which takes a duration) to tell it where to end, but if your videos are not all of exactly the same length, you will need to calculate this value for each file. You can get the length of a video using `ffprobe` like this:

```
ffprobe -i <file> -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

This will give you the length of the file in seconds. You will then need to subtract the desired amount (in your case, 1 second if you use `to` or 2 seconds if you use `t`) and feed the result into the appropriate flag in your ffmpeg command.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer!

Comment: However I'm not an expert and I think I need more help:

Comment: Now I’m using this batch command (it’s only removing the first second)

for %f in (“*.*”) do c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%f" -ss 00:00:01.000 -c:v copy -c:a copy “u:\footage\%f”

How exactly do I have to compose the batch command you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a Linux guy and only ever use Windows if my job requires it. I usually avoid platform-specific scripting languages, so my batch skills aren't the best. I edited the answer to include something that should probably work. FYI, there's a good resource on batch syntax here: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html Although I personally think your time would be better spent learning something cross-platform like Python.

Comment: I tried but I get this from the system: Invalid duration specification for to: !dur!

Comment: Well, like I said, I don't use Windows regularly, so I didn't test it. Looking at it again, you probably need to an an `/a` switch to the `set` command.  So `set /a dur=....`. Apparently this tells the script that you are assigning an arithmetic function to the variable, and it needs to be evaluated. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The problem is I'm not an expert and I don't know how to put in a script. I created a batch file but it's not working

Comment: Sorry to hear you're still having trouble. I believe I answered your question about how to properly form the ffmpeg command, but I don't think I'm going to be able to offer any more useful help with the batch script. You may want to start another question for specific help with that.